# How do I pipe a list of numbers straight from the shell into a command?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, syntax

How do I pipe a list of numbers straight from the shell into a command? For exampe something like this

```
[1,2,3,4] | sort
```

would give

```
1
2
3 
4
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the answers kindly posted so far . . . I ask this, because I want to quickly test and debug a console application that takes many numbers as it input without having to type lots of individual values followed by carriage returns. I'd like to just type in the 'one liner' and hit the up arrow now and then to replay the command. Ideally, I'd like to do this without using a text file containing the values (which would obviously be the most simple way to do this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming we're using single digit numbers - in which case `echo 1 2 4 3 | grep -o [1234567890]|sort` should to the trick. I think you'd have to adjust the regex for grep if its a multi digit number.

grep -o selects as per regex and prints it one per line

edit: and an even more elegant solution.

we still use echo, but with tr. This works with numbers bigger than one digit

`echo 10,2,4,3|tr ',' '\n'|sort -g`

tr is being told to replace a comma with a newline, and sort -g sorts in numerical order (assuming thats what you want sort for).

Assuming you *need* the square brackets in the list for some odd reason, you can remove it with

`echo [10,2,4,3]|tr '[:punct:]' ' '|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -g`

The additional tr command replaces any punctuation with a space.

Comment: Your last example doesn't work.  The first `tr '[:punct:]' ' '` turns any commas into spaces before the the second `tr ',' '\n'` would ever see them.

Comment: fixed I think - almost, now I have two spaces in front ... The square brackets so seem to make it a little tricky

Comment: Try `tr -d '[]' | tr ',' '\n'`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a "here" document using the `<<` in-line i/o redirection operator.  The shell looks for whatever token you give (in this example, `eof`) as the end-of-file marker for the here doc.

```
sort << eof
1
2
3
4
eof
```

Another way would be to iterate over the values, `echo`ing them into sort:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo $i; done | sort
```

If you'd like the `for` loop packaged up as a command, use a procedure:

```
list() for i in $*; do echo $i; done
list 1 2 3 4 | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ printf '%d\n' 1 3 2 4 | sort
1
2
3
4
```

or

```
$ echo $'1\n2\n4\n3' | sort
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: In some states, the second answer works better without the `$`.  I have gotten `echo '1\n2\n4\n3'` to give the output you show for `echo $'1\n2\n4\n3'`, while `echo $'1\n2\n4\n3'` itself outputs `$1`, `2`, `4`, and `3` (on separate lines).

Answer (score 2):

You can use cat

```
cat | sort 
1
2
4
3
^d (end of input)
```

Comment: Except for being slower, this is no different than `sort` all by itself.

Comment: @Nicole: The OP explains in an edit that `sort` is a metaphor for some other, unspecified program –– and that program _could_ be testing its standard input to see whether it is a tty, file, pipe, or whatever.

Comment: @Scott  And how is that different than `sort` as a metaphor for something else, but still all by itself.  The `cat |` adds nothing.

Comment: @Nicole: My point is that, if you type `umptyfratz` and then type some input (terminated by Ctrl+D), and then type `cat | umptyfratz` followed by the same input, you might get two different behaviors.  You said, “this is no different …”

Comment: @Scott How would you get different behaviors on pure text input just by inserting `cat |` into the pipeline?  I understand it's possible, e.g., by testing whether the input is a pipe or a keyboard then doing arbitrarily different things.  But I'm struggling to come  up with a real case in the real world.  If the input was in a "here document" (as in my own answer above) it's a pipe either way and there would definitely be no difference.

Comment: @Nicole Your second sentence is the answer to your question.  I didn’t say it was _likely_, but we don’t know what `umptyfratz` is (except we know that learnvst is currently debugging it), so who knows what funky code is in it?  As a plausible example, it might say `if (isatty(0))` go into full-screen mode (with cursor addressing, etc), otherwise, just treat stdout as a tty.  My point is that your unconditional statement is like “Election Day is the first Tuesday in November” and “Thanksgiving is the last Thursday in November”.  They are correct more than 50% of the time –– but less than 100%.

Comment: @Scott  Gotcha.  Your complaint has nothing to do with any real-life examples, only hypothetically contrived ones.  But it's a good excuse for splitting hairs.

Comment: @Nicole: Another thing: in your third comment above (“How would you get different behaviors …?”) you said “If the input was in a "here document" … it’s a pipe either way …”  Well, on my Linux system, it’s not –– a “here document” is a file.  I believe it’s been that way for a *long* time (and I’m almost as old as you).  You can test this by executing `ls –lL /dev/stdin` with various input sources (terminal, file, `/dev/null`, pipe, and “here document”).  Use `/proc/self/fd/0` if you don’t have `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: @Nicole: I could not find any statement that it’s supposed to work that way; maybe it’s an implementation choice.  However, I found two sites describing products that were implemented that way: [a `sh-posix(1)` man page at HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02267598/c02267598.pdf) (PDF file; go to the midpoint of page 27) and [a “Help” page in the “System management” section of the (IBM) AIX 7.1 Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.baseadmn%2Fdoc%2Fbaseadmndita%2Fredir_output_inline.htm) (with a stupid title).

Comment: @Nicole: A thought: consider how hard it would be for the shell to implement `cmd <<EOF0 3<<EOF3 4<<EOF4 5<<EOF5` with pipes.

Comment: @Nicole: I’m not picking on you; but I do like to split hairs.

Comment: I also like splitting hairs now and then, but these hairs might best be split in a chat room. :)

Comment: @Scott I'm usually on Windows, not Linux.  But I know exactly how hard it is to create here docs using pipes, not actual files. I know because that's how I did it when I wrote my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).  I'm surprised `bash` would actually write a file.

Comment: @Nicole: Does it bother you that your users might have written programs that depend on here documents being seekable?

Comment: @Scott, I released before `bash` and, no, my users are fine.  Pipes are much faster but I realized after my comment that I was able to use them cheaply because I'm multithreaded; `bash` is not and would have to fork to feed the pipe.  But let's move this offline.  Send me mail at hamiltonlabs.com.  If you run Windows, I'll give you a free copy of my work and we can talk about what I've done.

Answer (score 2):

The “super simple” answer: type the command, and then type the input.  (Strictly speaking, this is not piping.  The word “pipe” is vastly overused in reference to I/O redirection, and this wouldn’t even be I/O redirection, it’s just standard I/O.)  End with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (assuming you’re on some form of *nix or something Unix-like, and that you haven’t changed your EOF character).  For example:

> *(prompt)*> `sort –f
>
>   The
>
>   quick
>
>   brown
>
>   fox`
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
>
>   `brown
>
>   fox
>
>   quick
>
>   The`
>   *(prompt)*>

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> may echo as `^D`, and first line of the output may appear on the same line as this:

```
^Dbrown
fox
quick
The
```